# R. Setting value in data frame based on values in different data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, conditional-statements

Say I have two dataframes:

df.trial.params =

```
Session     Trial.Start    Trial.End    Trial.Num
1           30             50           1
1           51             80           2
2           30             50           1
2           51             80           2
3           30             50           1
3           51             80           2
```

df.data =

```
Session    Time
1          31
1          33
1          52
1          72
2          31
2          33
2          52
2          72
3          31
3          33
3          52
3          72
```

I want to add a column (df.data$trial.num), which is based off of parameters in df.trial.params. This matching is done in 2 steps:
Step 1: Match the session

```
if(df.data$Session == df.trial.params$Session)
```

Step 2: Match the time so that it sits within the trial start and end times

```
if((df.data$Time >= df.trial.params$Trial.Start) & (df.data$Time <= df.trial.params$Trial.End))
```

The end results would be this:

```
Session    Time    Trial.Num
1          31      1
1          33      1
1          52      2
1          72      2
2          31      1
2          33      1
2          52      2
2          72      2
3          31      1
3          33      1
3          52      2
3          72      2
```

I am really at a bit of a loss, as I have very limited experience with using R. I have seen a few posts using with() but I am not sure how to use multiple data frames with this.
Any and all help is appreciated, my apologies if this question has been answered elsewhere (I couldn't find it)

Edited to show desired final product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df.data)[df.trial.params, on = "Session", allow.cartesian=TRUE
     ][Time >=Trial.Start & Time <= Trial.End][,  (3:4) := NULL][]
#     Session Time Trial.Num
# 1:       1   31         1
# 2:       1   33         1
# 3:       1   52         2
# 4:       1   72         2
# 5:       2   31         1
# 6:       2   33         1
# 7:       2   52         2
# 8:       2   72         2
# 9:       3   31         1
#10:       3   33         1
#11:       3   52         2
#12:       3   72         2
```

---

Or using `foverlaps`

```
df.data1 <- transform(df.data, Trial.Start = Time, Trial.End = Time)[-2]
setDT(df.trial.params, key = c("Session", "Trial.Start", "Trial.End"))
setDT(df.data1, key = c("Session", "Trial.Start", "Trial.End"))
foverlaps(df.data1, df.trial.params, type="within")[,
               Time := i.Trial.Start][, c(1, 7, 4), with = FALSE]
#    Session Time Trial.Num
# 1:       1   31         1
# 2:       1   33         1
# 3:       1   52         2
# 4:       1   72         2
# 5:       2   31         1
# 6:       2   33         1
# 7:       2   52         2
# 8:       2   72         2
# 9:       3   31         1
#10:       3   33         1
#11:       3   52         2
#12:       3   72         2
```

Comment: This doesn't work for my actual data, I'm not sure why. Where does the 'Trial.Num' column get created?

Comment: @NathanLeggett  I posted another solution with `foverlaps`.  Hope it helps.  The `Trial.Num` was from the first data after merging.

Comment: @NathanLeggett For these kind of problems, `foverlaps` is the best and it should work.

Comment: In the last line:
foverlaps(df.data1, df.trial.params, type="within")[,Time := i.Trial.Start][, c(1, 7, 4), with = FALSE]
What does c(1,7,4) refer to? Columns?

Comment: @NathanLeggett  It is subsetting the columns as there are 7 columns in the output.

Comment: I think I got it to work by changing that last "c(1,7,4)" bit to "c(1:52)", as this returns all the column in my data set. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the data frame by *Session* and then filter by the time:

```
library(dplyr)
merge(df.trial.params, df.data, by = 'Session') %>% 
      filter(Time >= Trial.Start, Time <= Trial.End) %>% 
      select(Session, Time, Trial.Num)

#    Session Time Trial.Num
# 1        1   31         1
# 2        1   33         1
# 3        1   52         2
# 4        1   72         2
# 5        2   31         1
# 6        2   33         1
# 7        2   52         2
# 8        2   72         2
# 9        3   31         1
# 10       3   33         1
# 11       3   52         2
# 12       3   72         2
```

Comment: This doesn't run (the console has the '+' still)

Comment: Well. It works for me. Make sure you didn't miss a parenthesis and the data frame name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

watch out with using `if`, `if(df.data$Time >= df.trial.params$Trial.Start)` will check if the total column is the higher.
To loop through each row you will need the vectorised version `ifelse()`